# How to Segregate comman fields in Hibernate annotaion mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-mapping

I am using spring 3 and hibernate4.2 based annotation configuration in my project, I have number of database tables (view objects/entities) with two common fields createdDate & updatedDate.
I want to segregate these two fields. I thought of keeping these two fields in some class which acts as a superclass to all entities and  implementing this with table per subclass inheritance mapping.  I don't require any foreign key relation between this superclass and subclass entities.. can anyone please suggest me  a better solution with example..  Thank You.

Comment: Why do you need a better solution, what's wrong with yours?

Comment: try `@Embeddable and @Embedded`

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate the superclass with `@MappedSuperclass`.

From Hibernate Documentation Chapter: [5.1.6.4. Inherit properties from superclasses](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#d5e3306)

> This *(Inherit properties from superclasses)* is sometimes useful to share common properties through a technical
>   or a business superclass without including it as a regular mapped
>   entity (ie no specific table for this entity). For that purpose you
>   can map them as @MappedSuperclass.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date createdDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date updatedDate;
}


@Entity
class NormalEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    public Integer id
    ...
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for... I got a good example here [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `@MappedSuperclass`, only use this where the type is actually a subtype of the superclass which it clearly is not from reading your question.

Investigate `@Embedded` and `@Embeddable`, this is what your really want.

Tutorial: http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/example-embeddable-embedded-hibernate-annotation.php

Comment: How do you read this "...I thought of keeping these two fields in some class which acts as a superclass to all entities..."?